# Wear bar on snow shovel: whether and how to replace?

Tags: repair, rivets

Any tips on replacing the worn out metal wear bar on a snow shovel?

Should I simply buy a $4 flat aluminum bar and  some pop rivets?  About $8 total, vs $40 for a new shovel.

Seems obvious, just looking for advice from anyone who has tried it.

Not sure what the original bar is made of.  Seems stronger and longer-lasting than aluminum.  But doesn't rust.  And surely isn't stainless steel, not in a $40 shovel.  Thoughts?

[image]

Here is a picture of my actual shovel.

[image]

The wear bar is about 1/8 inch, and it's steel.  But some interesting features:

1. It is indented (as though countersunk, but bent not drilled) so the rivets are inset on the underside.  The bar can wear through entirely to the plastic without the rivets wearing at all.
2. It has a lip, and the plastic shovel has a corresponding ridge, along its *back edge*.   **I do not understand why.**

Comment: Alu will last longer than pkastic…

Comment: Don't know if pop rivets would be ridged/hold enough in plastic.  Solid rivets might be better.

Comment: Have done just that with thin-gauge steel bar and poprivets. Yes, the thin rivets do wear out, but are easily replaced. Construction adhesive, e.g., Liquid Nails, in addition to the rivets, helps. BTW, I've tried an aluminum strip, but it wears quickly and is so soft as to increase friction.

Comment: There are many different grades and treatments of aluminum.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I suspect that if I start in the direction of specifying the grade and treatment of aluminum, I will quickly exit the domain of saving money by not buying a new shovel.  I suspect also that Dr Pippick's specification was the same as mine would be: "whatever they have on the shelf at the hardware store".  Perhaps he'll elaborate.  (Although, I never said saving money was the objective did I?  "Build a better shovel"? Why not .. )

Comment: I've gotta admit. This is just something that has never crossed my mind to repair. I find the plastic and/or handle breaks before I've ever worn out a rub strip. I suppose with not that much snow and a gravel driveway, my shoveling doesn't do that much wearing on a hard surface.

Comment: @FreeMan I was wondering exactly that ... if you are lucky enough to wear out the bar before all the plastic parts disintegrate, is it time to cash in your chips and leave the casino?   The answer from d.george is encouraging, it suggests that an attempt to  repair is worthwhile especially if you start with a good robust shovel.

Comment: FWIW the original bar is galvanized https://www.suncast.com/sc3950.html

Comment: I discovered the shovel maker sells a repair "kit" with rivets for $6.  It's not on line, there is no reference to it on any web site.  You have to phone them.  When I receive it (more than a month in the future) I'll post an answer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik your comments on aluminum would make for a good answer, especially actual experience and noting increased friction.  I did not think of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have replaced the "wear edge"on my favorite snow shovel 2 times and will change it again this spring. I buy a 1/8" flat steel about 3/4" wide and pop rivet it to the shovel. I have found that it is better to pop rivet from the bottom instead of from the top to make the rivets last longer and not interfere with the concrete. Works great.

Comment: All aluminum is worthless for a wear edge. Steel is best although Stellite is better.

Comment: @blacksmith37 is Stellite something I can buy easily in a store in small quantities?  for example a bar 1/8 " x 1 " x 4ft ?  I've never seen it.

Comment: I wonder if a 1/8 " bar could be dented like the original one on my shovel (see new picture in Question) so that the rivets will not be exposed to wear?

Comment: With a big enough hammer and anvil, @jay613, why not?

Comment: You can't reasonably get Stellite so that is why steel is best. For heavy use like a municipal street plow the steel is hardened , but not for home owner equipment.

Answer (score 2):

D.george's answer remains my first choice as it is not brand-specific, but FWIW I did buy [replacement wear bars](https://support.suncast.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500011593702-Shovel-Wearstrip-Replacement-Instructions) for my shovel, they come with nuts an bolts that replace the original rivets and are designed to avoid contact with the ground.

And to answer the original question - yes, it is very worth it.  My favorite shovel has lasted now 15 years or more, still in like-new condition.  I've replaced the wear bar with one from the manufacturer  and also the "ergonomic handle" with a generic one from Amazon.   That's the handle mounted mid-way on the S-shaped handle.  They snap off when abused by teenagers angry with being assigned the task and angrier still with stubborn ice.

Replacing these is easy, much cheaper than a new shovel, and this is, after all, a DIY forum ... it's satisfying.

Comment: Angry teenager? I've never heard of such a thing!